# installing Oracle 11g r2 on linux 6.1

Tags: java, oracle-database

I am trying To Install the Oracle 11g r2 on Linux 6.1 but i am Not Successful since a couple of days.When I have done all prerequisites  for oracle 11 g .But When I run The Installer I got this Error

```
Checking Temp space: must be greater than 80 MB.   Actual 18741 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4095 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
    >>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,

Continue? (y/n) [n]
```

and after I press "y", I got this exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:821)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:804)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(Unknown Source)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:122)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1783)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:480)
        at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:758)
        at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
        at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
        at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
        at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:114)
        at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:132)
```

My environment variables in `~/.bash_profile` are:

```
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR

ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oracle; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl; export ORACLE_UNQNAME

ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1 export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=orcl export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
DISPLAY=oracle:0.0; export DISPLAY

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java; export JAVA_HOME
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Linux 6.1", is that RedHat? What's the java version you have installed (`java -version`)?

Comment: yes i am installing on red hat and java is not installed

Comment: The error comes from the fact that you're not running X. If this is a remote machine to which you have an SSH connection, run an X-client locally and connect using `ssh -X` to enable X11-forwarding. If this is a local machine, don't run installation on a text console.

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL, I did the following and solved this error.

If `xclock` is not installed, install it as shown below:

```
yum install xorg-x11-app*
```

then type `xclock`, and `xclock` will be displayed. Now, do this as root:

```
xhost +dwiba01-I114159.ca.com
su oracle
./runInstaller
```

Change `dwiba01-I114159.ca.com` to the domain you are connecting from.

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't work, double check if you use `su - oracle` because Using `su - oracle` will break X screen forwarding or proper display when using Oracle runInstaller.

So you need ssh the host with user oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to just install Oracle Java to resolve this issue. The instructions for doing so are available on Oracle's website.

- [What are the Linux x64 RPM Java installation instructions?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml)

You can download the most recent version of Java from this URL:

- [Java Downloads for Linux](http://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp)

You'll need to download the appropriate version for your architecture, 32-bit or 64-bit. I'd recommend downloading the RPM packages.

#### EDIT #1

Your issue is with the display variable, `$DISPLAY`. It may be set but it's unclear if you're doing this installation over SSH or on a locally accessed system. See this error:

```
>>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command 
   /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<
```

Try running that command, `/usr/bin/xdpyinfo` to confirm.

Comment: I have installed the java but error is same

Comment: i am running xhost+ and error shows `unable to open display ...`

Comment: The display is either not set or isn't accessible. Confirm that the env. var. DISPLAY is set, `echo $DISPLAY`.

Comment: `DISPLAY=oracle:0.0; export DISPLAY` sir this env variable is set as shown in post

Comment: What is `oracle` in that statement? The local machine's name or some remote computer you're connecting from?

Comment: this is host name of localhost machine

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the installer can't get at the X display. You probably need to start X as root (graphical login as root) to be able to do the install.

Yes, completely brain-dead. Who in her sane mind will run X as root? What correctly configured *database server* even has graphical tools installed, when it will be managed by CLI tools?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, I installed all GUI packages using yum then add:

```
$ xhost +<machinename>
$ su oracle
$ ./runInstaller
```